# File upload saving the folder instead of the file

Tags: c#, file-upload, telerik

I'm performing upload of files into DB with Telerik's ASP.NET RadAsyncpload, which is very similar to the normal fileUpload.

My problem is that, when using the variable to store the Data, it saves as "null". in alternative i tried to use Server.MapPath, which is for is turn saving the folder localtion instead of the File.

What am i doing wrong?

```
//partial class declarations
   (...)
   string Ficheiro = string.Empty;
   string FileTipo = string.Empty;
   byte[] fileBytes = null;

//Save method, triggered by save button after upload
  public void SaveFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListagemTimesheet model = new ListagemTimesheet();
      
        model.IDRecursoHumano = Convert.ToInt32(rdpInvestigadorE.Text);
        model.IDEstadoTimesheet = Convert.ToInt32(rcbEstado.SelectedValue);
        model.Observações = Obervaçoestxt.Text;
        model.AssinaturaTimesheet = txtAssinaturaTimesheet.Text;
        model.DataEnvio = DataEnvio.SelectedDate.Value;

        if (Objecto.ID > 0)
        {
            model.ID = Convert.ToInt32(FileID.Text);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ficheiro) && FileTipo != null)
            {

                model.FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Ficheiro); //FileName
                model.FileTipo = Path.GetExtension(FileTipo); //FileExtension
                model.FileContent = fileBytes; //Content null
                model.FileContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TargetFiles/ + model.FileName")); //Content saved is location of the folder

//Upload method
public void RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadAsyncUpload1.Visible = false;
        Stream fileStream = e.File.InputStream;
        Ficheiro = e.File.FileName; // sintaxe metodo
        FileTipo = e.File.ContentType;
        e.IsValid = true;
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length - 1 + 1];
        fileStream.Read(dados, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED!
I was missing copy the stream to the variable `fileBytes`.

```
public void RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
    {
            RadAsyncUpload1.Visible = false; //false
            var liItem = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            Ficheiro = e.File.FileName; // sintaxe metodo
            FileTipo = e.File.ContentType;
            e.IsValid = true;
            e.File.InputStream.Position = 0;
            fileBytes = new byte[e.File.InputStream.Length];
            for (int totalBytesCopied = 0; totalBytesCopied < e.File.InputStream.Length; )
                totalBytesCopied += e.File.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, totalBytesCopied, Convert.ToInt32(e.File.InputStream.Length) - totalBytesCopied); //conversao para bytes
            e.File.InputStream.Close();

            if (File.Exists("~/App_Data/RadUploadTemp"))
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
                e.File.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(
                    Path.Combine(RadAsyncUpload1.TargetFolder, e.File.GetNameWithoutExtension() + "1" + e.File.GetExtension())));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be reading your file data into a local variable called `dados`, but is never assigned to the global variable.

Your file data should most likely go into the `fileBytes` variable, to enable your `SaveFile` function to read the value.
So you should read the `fileStream` directly into your `fileBytes` variable.

```
...
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length - 1 + 1];
...
```

Full code

```
//Save method, triggered by save button after upload
  public void SaveFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListagemTimesheet model = new ListagemTimesheet();
      
        model.IDRecursoHumano = Convert.ToInt32(rdpInvestigadorE.Text);
        model.IDEstadoTimesheet = Convert.ToInt32(rcbEstado.SelectedValue);
        model.Observações = Obervaçoestxt.Text;
        model.AssinaturaTimesheet = txtAssinaturaTimesheet.Text;
        model.DataEnvio = DataEnvio.SelectedDate.Value;

        if (Objecto.ID > 0)
        {
            model.ID = Convert.ToInt32(FileID.Text);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Ficheiro) && FileTipo != null)
            {

                model.FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Ficheiro); //FileName
                model.FileTipo = Path.GetExtension(FileTipo); //FileExtension
                model.FileContent = fileBytes; // This will now be the data loaded from the filestream in your RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded function
                
                // This returns the path in the content because Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes simply changes the string path to a byte array
                //model.FileContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/TargetFiles/ + model.FileName")); //Content saved is location of the folder

//Upload method
public void RadAsyncUpload1_FileUploaded(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadAsyncUpload1.Visible = false;
        Stream fileStream = e.File.InputStream;
        Ficheiro = e.File.FileName; // sintaxe metodo
        FileTipo = e.File.ContentType;
        e.IsValid = true;
        
        // Read the file stream into your fileBytes variable
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileStream.Length - 1 + 1];
        fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately , the FileContent is saved as null. So there must be something else missing

Comment: I see I made a small mistake, the statement `fileStream.Read(dados, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));` should read `fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));`

Comment: yeah, i noticed that. I was also my miss. But the problem persists, do you have other idea of what it could be?